# Is it possible to set different resolution between console and X when Kernel Mode Setting is enabled?

Tags: fedora, monitors, kms

My LCD monitor is dying. It has white screen issue: when power on, it's black screen (power LED is flashing), after a while (maybe one hour), it turns to white screen. Then I need switch to different resolutions many many times (hundreds, maybe) to get the LCD monitor to work.

Currently, I'm using VNC to connect to my fedora 17 desktop from an Android phone, and switch resolutions from System Setting -> Display. It's difficult to switch resolutions in this way. So, I think if the console has a different resolution to the X Window resolution, then I can simply use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+[<kbd>F1</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>...] hotkeys to switch resolutions.

If I disabled [Kernel Mode Setting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode-setting) by passing `nomodeset` parameter to kernel, then the console resolution is different to X Window resolution. However, the X Windows does not get the native/best resolution (1680x1050) of the monitor, it only get 1280x1024 resolution which is listed in vesa modes (`vga=ask` kernel parameter).

So, before I buy a new monitor or fixed this monitor, is it possible to set different resolution between console and X when Kernel Mode Setting is enabled ?

---

**Edit (2012-11-28)**

I've sent LCD monitor to electrical appliance service shop and finally got it fixed, it was because of some [capacitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor)s failed.

And now I realize I can also change to a different lower resolution in X environment, then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+[<kbd>F1</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>...] hotkeys to switch resolutions. This can let me get lower resolution but same X:Y ratio as native/best resolution.

The answer for this question is still wanted.